# Could not find the App Center CLI. Install appcenter-cli using npm

Tags: xamarin, continuous-integration, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to run Xamarin UI tests on Visual Studio App Center (Azure DevOps Pipeline) and get error:

**(node:14661) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Could not find the App Center CLI. Install appcenter-cli using npm.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> webpack-cli@3.3.10 requires a peer of webpack@^4.x.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

You could install the latest version of Webpack and add it to your `devDependencies` with the following command:

```
npm i -D webpack@latest
```

About peer dependency of Webpack , you can refer to this [document](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/) .